# NetLogo - dying with a certain likelihood

Tags: netlogo

I would like to have agents with a certain variable level to die with a given likelihood.

This is my code:

```
  ask turtles [
    let choose precision(random-float 1) 2
    if var >= 18 AND var <= 24 AND if choose < 0.1 [ die ]
    if var >= 25 AND var <= 30 AND if choose >= 0.15 [ die ]
    if var >= 31 AND var <= 40 AND if choose >= 0.2 [ die ]
    if var >= 41 AND var <= 70 AND if choose >= 0.25 [ die ]
    if var >= 71 AND var <= 86 AND if choose >= 0.15 [ die ]
    if var > 86 [ die ]
  ]
```

However, it seems that NetLogo does not like stacked conditions and gives me the following error code:

`AND expected 1 input on the right, a TRUE/FALSE` while selecting this part of the code

`var >= 18 AND var <= 24 AND`.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try taking out the `if` after the `and` in each line

Comment: Of course, Luke C. Thank you! You can write this as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Glad that worked! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple conditions for a conditional like `if` or `ifelse` in NetLogo, you can link them together with logical operators like `and` and `or` without needing to repeat the conditional primitive- so:

`if var >= 18 AND var <= 24 AND if choose < 0.1 [ die ]`

becomes

`if var >= 18 and var <= 24 and choose < 0.1 [ die ]`